# SICP Ex 1.3 error ;Syntactic keyword may not be used as an expression: #[keyword-value-item 13]

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, sicp

Hey I am trying to write some scheme can you help me out here?

```
(define (square a b) (+ (* a a) (* b b)))

(define (sumsq x y z)
    (cond (and (< x y) (< x z) (square y z))
          (and (< y x) (< y z) (square x z))
          (else (square y z))))

(sumsq 1 2 3)
```

It gives me an error `;Syntactic keyword may not be used as an expression: #[keyword-value-item 13]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of parentheses are missing. This is the correct syntax for `cond`:

```
(define (sumsq x y z)
    (cond ((and (< x y) (< x z)) (square y z))
          ((and (< y x) (< y z)) (square x z))
          (else (square y z))))
```